# creating kendo combobox with autocomplete functionality in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a razor kendo combobox with the autocomplete functionality. It should exactly work the same way as that of Kendo AutoComplete. The problem I am facing is that the filter happens only when I hover out and then hover in to the kendo combobox and the
dropdown does not popup when the data is loaded. Can anyone please help me out with this.

Here is my View

```
@using Kendo.MVC.UI 
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("autoComplete")
  .DataTextField("CustomerName")
  .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetUserNames", "UserNames").Data("onStringChange"))
  .ServerFiltering(true))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:20%;" })
  .Suggest(true)
  .AutoBind(false)
  .MinLength(2)
)
```

Here is my Javascript

```
function onStringChange() {
  return {
    user: $("#autoComplete").val()
  };
}
```

Here is my Controller Action Method :

```
public JsonResult GetUserNames(string user)
{
  if (user != "")
  {
    _access = _data.GetUserNames(user);
  }
  return Json(_access, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: can you show how your object that you pass to combobox looks like ?

Comment: I have passed the object as a string ,
example :
hel

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it using the Kendo Autocomplete control.

View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                        .Name("autocompleteID")
                        .DataTextField("TextFieldName")
                        .DataSource(source =>
                        {
                            source.Read(read =>
                            {
                                read.Action("GetUserNames", "ControllerName");
                            })
                            .ServerFiltering(true);
                        }))
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Search([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        string filter = Request.Params["filter[filters][0][value]"];
        return Json(_data.GetUserNames(filter));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("IdUser")
.Placeholder("Select User")
.DataTextField("text")
.DataValueField("value")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "form-control" })
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.AutoBind(false)
.MinLength(3).DataSource(source =>
 {
  source.Read(read =>
   { 
read.Action("ServerFiltering_GetList", "Users").Data("onAdditionalData");
    })
     .ServerFiltering(true);
})
```

sending `text` to server. `text` is anything you type in combo.

```
 <script>
function onAdditionalData() {
   var filter = $('#IdUser').data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.filter();                  
    return {
           text: (filter.filters.length > 0) ? filter.filters[0].value : ''
           };
 }
 </script>
```

c#

```
  public JsonResult ServerFiltering_GetList(string text)
        {           
                var Result = _userSite.GetListUser(text);
                return Json(Result);           
        }
```